# Is it possible to run BOTH Javascript and TypeScript in a Nuxt 2 project?

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, plugins, nuxt.js

I have a `Nuxt 2.17.2` project that is 100% Javascript and I need to run a few SDKs that are 100% TypeScript.

I want to be able to configure my project so I can run BOTH TypeScript and Javascript, so I don't affect the already existing code.

How can I do that?

I am trying to test this by injecting a very simple function (via `plugins`) with a `*.ts` extension, after I followed the steps in https://typescript.nuxtjs.org.

This is what I have so far:

`src/plugins/myInjectedFunction.ts`

```
import Vue from 'vue'

declare module 'vue/types/vue' {
  interface Vue {
    $myInjectedFunction(message: string): void
  }
}

Vue.prototype.$myInjectedFunction = (message: string) => console.log(message)
```

`myInjectedFunctionTest.vue`

```
<template>
  <div>
    <button @click="$myInjectedFunction('Test')">Click me !</button>
  </div>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import { defineComponent } from 'vue'

export default defineComponent({
  mounted () {
    this.$myInjectedFunction('works in mounted')
  }
})
</script>
```

`vue-shim.d.ts`

```
declare module "*.vue" {
    import Vue from 'vue'
    export default Vue
}
```

`tsconfig.json`

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ES2018",
    "module": "ESNext",
    "moduleResolution": "Node",
    "lib": [
      "ESNext",
      "ESNext.AsyncIterable",
      "DOM"
    ],
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowJs": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "strict": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "~/*": [
        "./*"
      ],
      "@/*": [
        "./*"
      ]
    },
    "types": [
      "@nuxt/types",
      "@nuxt/typescript-build",
      "@types/node"
    ]
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ]
}
```

Problem is that when I run this I get:

```
TypeError: this.$myInjectedFunction is not a function
    at VueComponent.mounted (myInjectedFunction.vue:6:1)
    at invokeWithErrorHandling (vue.runtime.esm.js:3017:1)
    at callHook$1 (vue.runtime.esm.js:4032:1)
    at Object.insert (vue.runtime.esm.js:4427:1)
    at invokeInsertHook (vue.runtime.esm.js:6946:1)
    at Vue.patch [as __patch__] (vue.runtime.esm.js:7094:1)
    at Vue._update (vue.runtime.esm.js:3765:1)
    at Vue.updateComponent (vue.runtime.esm.js:3868:1)
    at Watcher.get (vue.runtime.esm.js:3446:1)
    at new Watcher (vue.runtime.esm.js:3436:1)
```

What am I missing or doing wrong?

Comment: Did you follow https://typescript.nuxtjs.org/guide/setup ? It obviously won't work without this. Nuxt needs to be aware of .ts files in plugins and needs to compile them. This looks like XY problem, generally any third-part TS library is .js+.d.ts, so it can be used in both JS and TS. @AluanHaddad It won't work if the project wasn't configured for TS, that it's not autoimported from plugins suggests that it's not

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Problem was I wasn't importing the plugins!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was I wasn't importing the plugin in the file `nuxt.config.js`.

I have been working lately with Nuxt 3 and this is not needed as it auto-imports the `src/plugins` directory.